# How do you iterate over an array of character arrays in c?

Tags: c, c-strings

Do you have to manually loop through the array once and get a count of the strlen of each character array, sum it, allocate destination with the summed value and then loop over the array again?

How do you find the size of the array that contains the arrays of characters so you can iterate over them?

Comment: Some code would help us understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like you want to copy the array of C strings. Is that right?

Comment: I want to eventually concatenate the strings in the array into a single string. Need to know how much memory space to allocate for the destination string. I don't get how you know what to put as the terminate condition in the for loop, i.e. what the length of the array is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do you find the size of the array that contains the arrays of characters so you can iterate over them?

There are two ways:

1. Record the number of strings in the array when you allocate it in a variable.
2. Allocate an extra `char*` at the end of the array and store a null pointer in it as a sentinel, similar to the way a NUL character is used to terminate a string.

In other words, you have to do your own bookkeeping when allocating the array because C won't give you the desired information. If you follow the second suggestion, you can get the total number of characters in the array of strings with

```
size_t sum_of_lengths(char const **a)
{
    size_t i, total;
    for (i = total = 0; a[i] != NULL; i++)
        total += strlen(a[i]);
    return total;
 }
```

Don't forget to reserve space for a `'\0'` when doing the actual concatenation.

Comment: There we go. Thanks that answers everything.

Comment: ... or just use sizeof(array)/sizeof(entry) to get the length if you really got an array (not a pointer - they are NOT the same). Many people (me as well for the past 10 yrs or so) think that arrays and pointers are the same, but they are not - arrays will just automatically degenerate to a pointer if needed. e.g. int a[10] ={0}; sizeof(a)/sizeof(int) will give u 10 ; int *a=malloc(10*sizeof(int)); sizeof(a) == sizeof(int *) in this case

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to make a string that is the concatenation of all of the strings in the array.

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. Make 2 passes as you suggest, summing the lengths in the first pass, allocating the destination string, and then appending the strings in the second pass
2. Make 1 pass. Start by allocating the buffer to some size. Append the strings, keeping track  of the total size. If you don't have enough room for a string, reallocate the buffer with `realloc()`. The most efficient method of reallocation will be to double the size of the buffer each time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to concatenate the strings. If so, yes. You have to know how much space you want before you allocate it.

In fact, you can use `realloc`, but it's really just copy the previous string every time, and much less effective.

Some code : (assuming `char *s[]` and `int n`)

```
int i,l=1;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) l+=strlen(s[i]);
char *r=malloc(l);
r[0]=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) strcat(r,s[i]);
```

Edit: As some comments, `strcat` is ineffective when you know the length. (I still prefer it since it allocate the memory in one time.) Some more effective code is:

```
int i,l=1;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) l+=strlen(s[i]);
char *r=malloc(l);
char *d=r;
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
 srtcpy(d,s[i]);
 d+=strlen(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: This use of `strcat` is incredibly expensive: it causes the algorithm to run in O(n²) time while it could be linear.

Comment: How can linear be accomplished? @asaelr part of my question is how to figure out what n is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *nstrdup(char **args);
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char * this;

this = nstrdup(argv+1);
printf("[%s]\n", this );

return 0;
}

char *nstrdup(char **args)
{
size_t len, pos;
char **pp, *result;

len = 0;
for (pp = args; *pp; pp++) {
        len += strlen (*pp);
        }
result = malloc (1+len);

pos = 0;
for (pp = args; *pp; pp++) {
        len = strlen (*pp);
        memcpy(result+pos, *pp, len);
        pos += len;
        }
result[pos] = 0;
return result;
}
```

Comment: I dont like meta. (I dont understand the interface). I do think that people that edit whitespace (into some kind of corporate canonical form) are lower lif forms. Please go away. **JUST DONT TOUCH MY SOURCE**  you whitespae editors. Please go back to java if you cannot read source.

Comment: [meta] please add an option to accept / REJECT these bogus whitespace-nazi edits.